# Is there a way to seek forward/backward in duckduckgo audio preview?

Tags: audio, duckduckgo

I tried left/right arrows but it would get me to the previous/next song.

Comment: Unlikely since you don't can't seek ahead on the track either

Comment: In soundcloud you can seek fd/bk with right/left or with 1,2,3,4...9 (10%,20%,30%...), just like in youtube.